# Plot 3D density

Tags: plotting

I have data that is in four columns.  The x y and z are just the coordinates and the fourth is my data.  This is not a function.  This is electron density in a copper cell and I'm trying to display it in a way that makes sense.  Any help would be appreciated.  I was semi-successful in gnuplot but it was hard to see and I could only specify certain boundaries.  using  `($1:$2:($4>0 && $4<2 ? $3/0)` This might be slightly wrong, but you get the picture.  I was saying to only plot z if the data was between certain bounds.  There must be a better way and I need your help.  Thanks.  Here is the structure.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `ListContourPlot3D`? By the way, your title is misleading: this is a 3D density, that is, a density over a three-dimensional region.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19575/what-are-the-possible-ways-of-visualizing-a-4d-function-in-mathematica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dens = Table[{x, y, z, E^-Norm[{x, y, z}]^2}, {x, -1, 1, .1}, {y, -1,  1, .1}, {z, 0, 1, .1}]; 
ListContourPlot3D[Flatten[dens, 2], 
 Contours -> Range[.1, .3, .03], Mesh -> None, 
 ContourStyle -> Opacity[.3], BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think `BoxRatios->Automatic` is more useful generally, unless you want to force some particular ratios. `Automatic` makes scales of all directions the same, so that e.g. for a sphere you'll get a sphere not an ellipsoid, without having to think what your `PlotRange` is.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with *Mathematica 11*, you can use [`ListDensityPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot3D.html) function. Taking [Dr. belisarius's example data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44271/5208), here's the plot of it:

```
dens = Table[{x, y, z, E^-Norm[{x, y, z}]^2}, {x, -1, 1, .1}, {y, -1, 1, .1}, {z, 0, 1, .1}];
ListDensityPlot3D[Flatten[dens, 2], PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image: Output of ListDensityPlot3D]

Or, if you want it to look more like a density cloud instead of jelly, you can tweak some options:

```
ListDensityPlot3D[Flatten[dens, 2], PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[0.95, 0.6, 0.15] &), OpacityFunction -> (#^4/5 &)]
```

[image]