# How to plot four sets of data

Tags: plotting

```
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100];
b = RandomReal[{10, 20}, 100];
c = RandomReal[{100, 200}, 100];
d = RandomReal[{50, 60}, 100*100*100];
```

I have a simple program which generates 4 sets of data. Now I have to represent these data in a sensible way. The lists `a`, `b` and `c` as dimensions 1 $\times$ 100, and the dimension of `d` is  $ 100^3 $.

We have a difficulty in representing anything beyond 3D space. How to make a sensible plot with these data? Is there anything *Mathematica* can offer for visualization?

Comment: There are [several questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=4D+%5Bplotting%5D) about plotting 4D data.  [This one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44270/plot-3d-density) seems like a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### ListDensityPlot3D

Combine `a`,`b`,`c` and `d` into a list of 4-tuples and use [`ListDensityPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot3D.html):

```
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100];
b = RandomReal[{10, 20}, 100];
c = RandomReal[{100, 200}, 100];
d = RandomReal[{50, 60}, {100*100*100, 1}];
abcd = Join[Tuples[{a, b, c}], d, 2];
ListDensityPlot3D[abcd, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

#### Graphics3D

Alternatively, you can use the rescaled version of `d` with the option [`VertexColors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexColors.html) in `Graphics3D`:

```
d = RandomReal[{50, 60}, 100*100*100];
coords = Tuples[{a, b, c}];
colors = ColorData["TemperatureMap"] /@ Rescale[d];
Legended[Graphics3D[{Opacity[.1], Point[coords, VertexColors -> colors]}, 
  ImageSize -> 500, BoxRatios -> 1, Axes -> True], 
 BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {50, 60}}]]
```

[image]

#### BubbleChart

Finally, you can take a random sample of 4-tuples and use it with [`BubbleChart3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart3D.html) with bubble colors and sizes based on the last dimension of input data:

```
downsampled = RandomSample[abcd, 10000];
BubbleChart3D[downsampled, BubbleSizes -> {.01, .02}, 
 ChartStyle -> Opacity[.5], ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 ChartLegends -> BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {50, 60}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying to visualize variation of d with respect to a, b, c . Meaning a in x axis, b in y-axis and c in the z-axis , and somehow to put a point in this 3D plot which represents d

Comment: @acoustics, please see the updated version.