# Plot a data of four dimension

Tags: plotting

I have a confusion recently about the visualization of data with four dimension,like as `{x,y,z,color}`. This is my current solution.

```
data = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1ZKU.png"],"Byte"]]]];
front = data[[All, 1 ;; 3]];
back = data[[All, 4]];
Graphics3D[Point[front, VertexColors -> Hue /@ Rescale[back]]]
```

the effect like the picture.

[image]

it is not my intention.i want get a cube whose color be determined by the fourth element of the list.

I have an another try like this.

```
Style[ConvexHullMesh[front]]
```

[image]

the shape is contented to me.But I cannot render it by what I want to.Can anybody help me?

Comment: Something like: [19575](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19575/5478)?

Comment: @Kuba,yeah,thk your concern this problem.I have read that some times,but there are two difference,first,the first solution's point is not a face.the scene is same to my first picture. the scond solution 's data isn't a coordinates.so i want to get a new method.

Comment: and all my data is the surface of a cube.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{}], 
GraphicsComplex[front, 
MeshCells[DelaunayMesh[front], 2], VertexColors -> Hue /@ back]}]

MeshCoordinates[DelaunayMesh[front]] == front

(*True*)
```

[image]

Comment: `MeshCoordinates[front][[1]]` is equivalent to `front`.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Hi, thanks for pointing out that, that might be a typo here though the same to front, my first try is `MeshCoordinates[DelaunayMesh[front]]`

Comment: Also with some fiddling it seems that `VertexColors->Hue/@(Rescale@back)`yield a more meaningful picture.

Answer (score 2):

After version 10.2, we can directly plot it:

```
ListDensityPlot3D[data, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

[image]