# How do I make 4D plot in Mathematica from Excel data with two different graphical representation?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, visualization, plot-themes

I have some experimental data in excel format containing 50 rows and 4 columns (x, y, z, A). I want to first import the excel file into mathematica and then make TWO different plots simultaneously and placed side by side in my final output. My intended representations should look like the following graphs:

[image: Figure 1] [image: Figure 2]

However, I do not know how to do this such that I could select any of the columns as the coloured surface given by the legend on the right (I dont want to be limited to only A (x,y,z) but some other views like z(x,y,A) or x(y,z,A)). I need the coloured bar for the second plot also. Comments and suggestions would be appreciated.

I generated a sample data - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0gYqYOawaCcZjJ3andjZzhHMzA

Comment: closely related: [**19575**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19575/5478) and maybe a duplicate: [**20023**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20023/5478)

Comment: Take a look at linked topics and let us know if you get stuck. And if so you need to provide data sample to work with anyway.

Comment: I have checked the linked topics, they do not help my situation presently. Once you guys get me started, I have the feeling the information on the linked pages will strengthen my capabilities. Thanks