# Visualize function with 4 variables

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization

I have a function F that maps the xyzt space to a set of reals, more clearly:

```
F = 2 - x - 0.5 y - 2 z - 1.5 t;
```

with all varialbes x, y, z, t in [0,1] range.

I would like to visualize F to see how it varies, maximum, minimum values, etc.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Clearly we run out of dimensions to plot so you need to decide what do you want to see, which is not really a Mathematica question. You can take a look about related, simpler cases of [R^3->R functions.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=4D), lookup related functions etc. When you are stuck with implementation of anything specific, let us know.

Comment: You could, for each instance of time, visualize 4D like in [what-are-the-possible-ways-of-visualizing-a-4d-function-in-mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19575/what-are-the-possible-ways-of-visualizing-a-4d-function-in-mathematica)  Currently you have 5D, which is not possible.  So you need to cut it down to 4D by showing each instance of time.

Comment: Well, something along the lines of `Manipulate[
 DensityPlot3D[
  2 - x - 0.5 y - 2 z - 1.5 t, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}],
 {t, 0, 1}
 ]` could be done, but its far from being beautiful.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: I've just tried it but it is hard to understand and get some meaningful infor. From the plot, how to know where is the origin, which axis y, y, z, t is?

Comment: You can add labels for the axes (and the exes themselves if you cannot see them, yet) with `Manipulate[ DensityPlot3D[ 2 - x - 0.5 y - 2 z - 1.5 t, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True], {t, 0, 1}]`. Click on the small plus-sign next to the slider control in the top in order to visualize the current value of t. As is, the coloring is not consistent for different values of t. This might get fixed with `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` (and by specifying a suitable `ColorFunction`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A proposal.

```
F = 2 - x - 1/2 y - 2 z - 3/2 t;

Minimize[{F, 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1, 0 <= z <= 1, 0 <= t <= 1}, {x, y, z, t}]

(*   {-3, {x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 1, t -> 1}}   *)

Maximize[{F, 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1, 0 <= z <= 1, 0 <= t <= 1}, {x,y, z, t}]

(*   {2, {x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0, t -> 0}}   *)

tab = Table[
        ContourPlot3D[F, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
        Contours -> {-(29/10), -(5/2), -(21/10), -(17/10), -(13/10), -(9/
     10), -(1/2), -(1/10), 3/10, 7/10, 11/10, 3/2, 19/10}, 
     ContourStyle -> Table[Hue[.8 n/12], {n, 0, 12}], 
     AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
     PlotLabel -> {{"t = ", t}, {"Max=", 
   2 - (3 t)/2}, {"Min=", -(3/2) (1 + t)}}], {t, 0, 1, 1/20}];

ListAnimate[tab, 1, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

And here, how Maximum and Minimum varies with t.

```
Simplify[Maximize[{F, 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1, 0 <= z <= 1, 
    0 <= t <= 1}, {x, y, z}], {0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1, 0 <= z <= 1, 
    0 <= t <= 1}]

(*   {2 - (3 t)/2, {x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0}}   *)

Simplify[Minimize[{F, 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1, 0 <= z <= 1, 
     0 <= t <= 1}, {x, y, z}], {0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1, 0 <= z <= 1, 
     0 <= t <= 1}]

(*   {-(3/2) (1 + t), {x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 1}}   *)
```

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to assume you need to see the plot for only two coordinates, and just have two plots side by side with a Locator choosing which coordinate pair to use to "cut" the 4D space.

```
SetOptions[DensityPlot,
  ImageSize -> 300
  , PlotLegends -> Automatic
  , PlotRange -> {-2, 2}
  ];

DynamicModule[
 {
  xx = 0.5,
  yy = 0.5,
  zz = 0.5,
  tt = 0.5
  },
 Dynamic@Row[{
    With[{
      z = zz,
      t = tt
      },
     Show[
      DensityPlot[
       2 - x - 0.5 y - 2 z - 1.5 t
       , {x, 0, 1}
       , {y, 0, 1}
       , FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}
       , PlotLabel -> Row@{2 - x - 0.5 y - Sin[z] - 1.5 t}
       ],
      Graphics@Locator[Dynamic[{xx, yy}]]
      ]
     ],
    With[{
      x = xx,
      y = yy
      },
     Show[
      DensityPlot[
       2 - x - 0.5 y - 2 z - 1.5 t
       , {z, 0, 1}
       , {t, 0, 1}
       , FrameLabel -> {"z", "t"}
       , PlotLabel -> Row@{2 - x - 0.5 y - Sin[z] - 1.5 t}
       ],
      Graphics@Locator[Dynamic[{zz, tt}]]
      ]]
    }]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may use `DensityPlot3D` and `Manipulate`.

`DynamicModule` is used to hold the `min` and `max` values of `f` for a given `t`.  This is used in the `OpacityFunction` to enable exploration of the "density" for a given `t`.

With

```
f[x_, y_, z_, t_] := 2 - x - 0.5 y - 2 z - 1.5 t
```

Then

```
DynamicModule[{min, max},
 Manipulate[
  {min, max} =
   Through[{Minimize, Maximize}[
        {f[x, y, z, t], {{x}, {y}, {z}} \[Element] Interval[{0, 1}]}, 
        {x, y, z}, Reals]
    ][[All, 1]];
  DensityPlot3D[f[x, y, z, t], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
   PlotLegends -> Automatic,
   PlotPoints -> ControlActive[4, 40],
   PerformanceGoal -> ControlActive["Speed", "Quality"],
   OpacityFunction -> Interval[{min, First@o}, {Last@o, max}],
   OpacityFunctionScaling -> False],
  {{t, .5}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{o, {-1, 1}, "Opacity"}, Dynamic@min, Dynamic@max, IntervalSlider, 
   Method -> "Push", MinIntervalSize -> .1}
  ]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.