# Plot a 3D function defined in cylindrical coordinates with azimuthal symmetry

Tags: plotting

I have a function defined in cylindrical coordinates

```
rho[r_, z_] :=  2 E^(-(z^2/200))BesselJ[0,0.16 r] (-0.025 + 1/100 (1 +2 Log[E^(-(z^2/200)) BesselJ[0, 0.16 r]]));
```

This function is defined in a system with azimuthal symmetry, thus the system has no theta dependence. How will I plot such function in mathematica

Comment: Please check `SphericalPlot3D`.

Comment: The sphericalplot3D plots effectively if you have theta dependence. Here I do not have a theta dependence.

Comment: Use `DensityPlot3D` and write **r**=sqt(x^2+y^2)

Comment: Check [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19575/what-are-the-possible-ways-of-visualizing-a-4d-function-in-mathematica)