# Adding color legend to a 4d plot

Tags: plotting, legending

I have to plot a function of three varaibles $F(\theta,\beta,\gamma)$ with version 10.0 and I thought to follow the first advice of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19582/8822) answer, so my plot is given by:

```
xyz = Flatten[
   Table[{i, j, k}, {i, 0, Pi, 0.1}, {j, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}, {k, 0, Pi, 
     0.1}], 2];

f[x_, y_, z_] := Cos[x] Sin[y] Cos[z];

Graphics3D[
 Point[xyz, VertexColors -> (Hue /@ Rescale[f[##] & @@@ xyz])], 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {\[Theta], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}]
```

I want to add a color legend to it how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general way would be to use

```
Legended[
 Graphics3D[
  Point[xyz, VertexColors -> (Hue /@ Rescale[f[##] & @@@ xyz])], 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {\[Theta], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}],
 BarLegend[Hue]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, you only need to scale the ticks of the legend, but I'm sure you find out yourself how this works by looking up the documentation of [`BarLegend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html).

Comment: For clarification in this answer here, does the use of `Rescale` serve the same purpose as `ColorFunctionScaling->False`?

Comment: @CATrevillian I just copied the code from the OP. If anything, then the `Rescale` acts like `ColorFunctionScaling -> True` because it rescales the whole dataset of values in the range [0,1]. However, for `VertexColors` you need to rescale the values yourself opposed to things like `Plot` that do it for you.